# SVN fails with hidden files

Tags: svn, hidden-files

I am running subversion 1.6.17 on Ubuntu Server 14.04 and I cannot commit to the server if I add any hidden files. For example, attempting to commit with the file /lib/hammer.js-1.1.3/.jshintrc results in the following error:

```
Transmitting file data ..........svn: E195023: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E195023: Changing file '/var/www/hybrid/lib/hammer.js-1.1.3/.jshintrc' is forbidden by the server
svn: E175013: Access to '/svn/project/hybrid/!svn/wrk/e2e01aff-e5e8-4019-a9b3-7c5189ebf57c/lib/hammer.js-1.1.3/.jshintrc' forbidden
svn: E175002: Additional errors:
svn: E175002: PUT of '/svn/project/hybrid/!svn/wrk/e2e01aff-e5e8-4019-a9b3-7c5189ebf57c/lib/hammer.js-1.1.3/.jshintrc': 403 Forbidden
```

I've done some googing but I can't pinpoint what is causing this issue. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: What SVN protocol are you using? Are you using `http://`, `svn://`, or `file://`? Is your working directory outside of the repository directory? I have no problems committing hidden files, so I think the issue might be your setup. Do you have an authorization file or access file? Can you give us a bit more information?

Comment: Check pre-commit hook on server for dotted-files restrictions